# Criteria for a linear combination of two Hermitian matrices to intersect the cone of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

Given two Hermitian matrices, $H$ and $K$, I am wondering if there are existing results on whether there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$a H + b K \succ 0$$

where $M \succ 0$ denotes that Hermitian matrix $M$ is positive definite.

Comment: If you consider symmetric matrices, this is almost exactly a semidefinite program in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Pick two $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ matrices and then apply Sylvester's criterion.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo This is very helpful! Tho I don't know much about SDP, Sylvester's criterion is definitely something I can utilize.